# Make media key act as INSERT in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, media-keys

I've bought a C3TECH wireless keyboard/mouse, it doesn't have any special driver or software (just plug and play into the computer).

Althrough the keyboard have media keys, it doesn't have a INSERT key, and since i have some games (like F1 Challenge 99 02) who needs this key i'm searching for ways (preferably without additional software) to "remap" the "music" media key to be INSERT instead.

For reference below is a image of the keyboard with the music media key circled:

[image]

Comment: Should be easy enough, but with additional software : [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: The is an "Insert" key on the numpad.

Comment: Strangely it doesnt work no matter what is the NumLock state (on or off)